# Firestore Query using DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck and need help. What I want to achieve is, to retrieve all the documents from my Firestore collection by their timestamp using a Date Picker Dialog.

this is my code for the bottom picker dialog

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int YEAR = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int MONTH = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int DATE = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);

                    CharSequence charSequence = DateFormat.format("MMM dd, yyyy EEEE", cal);
                    Log.d("TAG", "onDateSet: "+charSequence);


                }
            }, YEAR, MONTH, DATE);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

My question is since the Firestore timestamp has two parameters which is the Date and time, can I query it with only the date from my time picker dialog?

Comment: Sure you can, as long as the selected Date is between some specific dates. What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm trying what Mofidul Islam suggested below.  I created two Calendar instances then convert them to a String with a format of "MMMM dd, yyyy". the first is the current date with 00:00 time and another with also 00:00 time but a day ahead. And in my query .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo and .whereLessThanOrEqualTo. But I'm receiving nothing from my firestore. But I'm retrieving nothing from my firestore database.

Comment: This is my query: query = collectionReference.document(Constants.CURRENT_DOC).collection("timecard")                         .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("time_in",dateFrom).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("time_in"dateTo);

Comment: That's not gonna work. You need Date objects. Show us your database schema and the elements you want to filter, so I can provide the right query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume the selected date is 7 Oct,2021
You can just make two DateTime range

- 1.7 Oct 2021 00:00
- 2.7 Oct 2021 23:59

Now you can query with date range like greater than and less then on timestamp field in firestore